# Neural Network (operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,713) (713,18) )

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, logistic-regression, broadcast

I am currently taking the Deep Learning specialization by Deeplearning.ai on Coursera and am on the first assignment that requires implementing Neural Network with Logistic Regression mindset. The problem is that the assignment is implementation of Neural Network as Logistic Regression function for **UNSTRUCTURED DATA (IMAGES)**. I have successfully completed the assignment, getting all the expected outputs. However, I am now trying to use the coded Neural Network for **STRUCTURE DATA** but come across broadcast error. Part of the code is as below :

***The dataset code***

```
path_train = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\Research Paper\Research Paper Feature Sets\Balanced Feature Sets\Balanced Train combined scores.csv'
path_test = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\Research Paper\Research Paper Feature Sets\Balanced Feature Sets\Balanced Test combined scores.csv'

df_train = pd.read_csv(path_train)
#df_train = df_train.to_numpy()

df_test = pd.read_csv(path_test)
#df_test = df_test.to_numpy()

x_train = df_train.iloc[:,1:19]
x_train = x_train.to_numpy()
x_train = x_train.T

y_train = df_train.iloc[:,19]
y_train = y_train.to_numpy()
y_train = y_train.reshape(y_train.shape[0],1)
y_train = y_train.T

x_test = df_test.iloc[:,1:19]
x_test = x_test.to_numpy()
x_test = x_test.T

y_test = df_test.iloc[:,19]
y_test = y_test.to_numpy()
y_test = y_test.reshape(y_test.shape[0],1)
y_test = y_test.T

print ("Number of training examples: m_train = " + str(m_train))
print ("Number of testing examples: m_test = " + str(m_test))
print ("train_set_x shape: " + str(x_train.shape))
print ("train_set_y shape: " + str(y_train.shape))
print ("test_set_x shape: " + str(x_test.shape))
print ("test_set_y shape: " + str(y_test.shape))
```

***Output of Dataset Code***

```
Number of training examples: df_train = 713
Number of testing examples: df_test = 237
x_train shape: (18, 713)
y_train shape: (1, 713)
x_test shape: (18, 237)
y_test shape: (1, 237)
```

***The propagate function code***

```
def propagate(w,b,X,Y) :

    m = X.shape[1]

    A = sigmoid((w.T * X) + b)

    cost = (- 1 / m) * np.sum(np.dot(Y,np.log(A)) + np.dot((1 - Y), np.log(1 - A)))

    dw = (1 / m) * np.dot((X,(A - Y)).T)
    db = (1 / m) * np.sum(A - Y)

    assert(dw.shape == w.shape)
    assert(db.dtype == float)
    cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    assert(cost.shape == ())

    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}

    return grads, cost
```

***The optimize and model functions***

```
**def optimize**(w,b,X,Y,num_iterations,learning_rate,print_cost) :

costs = []

for i in range(num_iterations) :

    # Cost and gradient calculation
    grads, cost = propagate(w,b,X,Y)

    # Retrieve derivatives from gradients
    dw = grads['dw']
    db = grads['db']

    # Update w and b
    w = w - learning_rate * dw
    b = b - learning_rate * db

    if i % 100 == 0:
        costs.append(cost)

    # Print the cost every 100 training iterations
    if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
        print ("Cost after iteration %i: %f" %(i, cost))

    params = {"w": w,
          "b": b}

    grads = {"dw": dw,
         "db": db}

    return params, grads, costs

**def model**(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, num_iterations = 2000, learning_rate = 0.5, print_cost = False) :

# initialize parameters with zero
w, b = initialize_with_zeros(X_train.shape[0])

# Gradient descent (≈ 1 line of code)
parameters, grads, costs = optimize(w,b,X_train,Y_train,num_iterations,learning_rate,print_cost)

# Retrieve parameters w and b from dictionary "parameters"
w = parameters["w"]
b = parameters["b"]

# Predict train/test set examples (≈ 2 lines of code)
Y_prediction_train = predict(w,b,X_train)
Y_prediction_test = predict(w,b,X_test)

 # Print train/test Errors
print("train accuracy: {} %".format(100 - np.mean(abs(Y_prediction_train - Y_train)) * 100))
print("test accuracy: {} %".format(100 - np.mean(abs(Y_prediction_test - Y_test)) * 100))


d = {"costs": costs,
     "Y_prediction_test": Y_prediction_test, 
     "Y_prediction_train" : Y_prediction_train, 
     "w" : w, 
     "b" : b,
     "learning_rate" : learning_rate,
     "num_iterations": num_iterations}

return d
```

***Model Function output***

```
Cost after iteration 0: 0.693147
train accuracy: -0.1402524544179613 %
test accuracy: 0.4219409282700326 %
```

When I run the code, I get `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,713) (713,18)` at `A = sigmoid((w.T * X) + b)`. I am pretty new to neural networks and usage of numpy, so I can't figure out the problem. Any and all help would be really appreciated. The entire .ipynb file containing the entire code can be [downloaded from here](https://www27.zippyshare.com/v/QP6iaFH4/file.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` operator is elementwise multiplication, and your arrays have incompatible shapes. You want matrix multiplication, which you can do with [`np.matmul()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) or with the `@` operator:

```
A = sigmoid(w.T @ X + b)
```

A lot of ML, especially neural nets, is about keeping the shapes of things straight. Check the shapes of your `w`, `X`, and `Y` — they should be: `(features, 1)`, `(features, m)`, `(1, m)` respectively, where `features` is 18 for you, and `m` is 713.

You should also then be able to make sure that the shape of `A` matches `Y`.

Comment: Now I get the error `ValueError: shapes (1,713) and (1,18) not aligned: 713 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)`  at `cost = (- 1 / m) * np.sum(np.dot(Y,np.log(A)) + np.dot((1 - Y), np.log(1 - A)))`

Comment: I spotted the issue (I think) and modified my answer.

Comment: So I fixed, ensuring that the shapes are straight. However, now I am getting `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'T'` at `dw = (1 / m) * np.dot((X,(A - Y)).T)`. I checked everything and none of the used variables are tuples. X, A, w, m and Y are all np.ndarrays

Comment: @SteviG Watch the parentheses in that line. The `.T` is attached to `(X, (A - Y))` which is a tuple. It should be on `(A - Y)`.

Comment: I see the extra parenthesis was causing the problem. However, editing the code to make it as suggested, it now gives `ValueError: shapes (713,18) and (713,18) not aligned: 18 (dim 1) != 713 (dim 0)` at the same line. I swear I have implemented different ML algorithms with same same data using `sklearn library` but this is all new and confusing to me :(

Comment: Okay, I had another look at what's going on and I think you went wrong earlier. It looks like you actually need the shape of `X` to be opposite of the usual shape (such as `sklearn` wants, for example). So that's a bit confusing. Your `m = X.shape[1]` line was correct, but it was the shape of `X` itself that was wrong. So transpose it, and make sure the other shapes match as in my edited answer.

Comment: Did it. Still getting Value error, this time its `ValueError: shapes (1,713) and (1,713) not aligned: 713 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)`. I have updated my code to show the changes made to the shapes of the w, X and Y. They are the same as mentioned in the edited answer

Comment: This is just multiplying `Y` and `A`, essentially, so their shapes have to be compatible. You can either transpose one of them, or use elementwise multiplication. That is, either do `Y.T @ np.log(A)` or `sum(Y * np.log(A))`, whichever one makes the most sense to you. (Same idea for the other term of the cost function.)

Comment: hanks it works fine now. I have another question. I am running the model using the line d = model(x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test,num_iterations=2000,learning_rate=0.005,print_cost=True). Here the number of iterations are clearly 2000 and the neural network is supposed to print the cost and accuracies after every 100 iterations. However, it only prints the cost and the accuracies for only iteration 0. Also despite using `abs` I get a negative value for `train accuracy` I have updated the code to show the predict function and its output. Any help would be appreciated again :)

Comment: Glad it worked out. As for the new question: I think you should undo that change and ask a new question on SO, or this one will make no sense to anyone later.

Comment: If I open a new thread, it will be marked as a duplicate of this one and all the comments will be about duplication

Comment: I don't think so. It's a different issue. Right now this question doesn't make a lot of sense, because your original problem is solved.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I will explore it a bit more myself and then if it persists, will open a new thread. Don't want to post every single problem I encounter here. Thanks for the help once again. I have upvoted and accepted your answer to help anyone else should they also encounter the same problem